# Some of my LULCs do not show up in classification

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, classification, landsat, feature-class

I am trying to do LULC classification with seven classes using Landsat 8. when I finalize the classification, some classes do not show up in the report.

Here is the gee link https://code.earthengine.google.com/c3490c71ed4553bd27e0f32e05d63d11.

Below is my code:

```
// Define the area of interest

var roi = ee.FeatureCollection(provinces)
Map.addLayer(roi, {}, 'Lao PDR Provinces', false);
Map.centerObject(roi, 6);

// Cloudfree composite Landsat 8

var image = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite({
  collection: l8raw.filterDate('2022-01-01', '2022-12-31'),
  asFloat: true
});

var trueColorVis = {min: 0, Max: 0.3, bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']};
Map.addLayer(image.clip(roi), trueColorVis, 'composite');

// Create training data (for bands, you can also choose any of the 11 Bands)

var label = "Class";
var bands = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7'];
var input = image.select(bands);

// Designations 0= Water; 1 = Settlement; 2 = Crop; 3 = Forest, 4 = Degraded forest, 5 = Plantation, 6 = Barren land

var training = ee.FeatureCollection(trainingpts);

// Overlay the points on the landsat Image

var trainImage = input.sampleRegions({
  collection: training,
  properties: [label],
  scale: 30
});

print(trainImage);

// breakdata into two (train/ test)
var trainingData = trainImage.randomColumn();
var trainSet = trainingData.filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('random', 0.7));
var testSet = trainingData.filter(ee.Filter.greaterThanOrEquals('random', 0.7));

// Classification model (CART)
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileCart().train(trainSet, label, bands);

// Classify the landsat image

var classified = input.classify(classifier);

var validation = testSet.classify(classifier)

// Get a confusion matrix representing resubstitution accuracy.
// var trainAccuracy = classifier.confusionMatrix();

var testAccuracy = validation.errorMatrix(label, 'classification')
print('Validation error matrix:', testAccuracy)
print('Validation overall accuracy:', testAccuracy.accuracy())
print("Consumer's accuracy:", testAccuracy.consumersAccuracy());
print("Producer's accuracy:", testAccuracy.producersAccuracy());
print("Kappa coefficient", testAccuracy.kappa());

// Define Visualiazation

var landcoverPaletter = [
  '#0000FF',
  '#FF0000',
  '#FFFF00',
  '#008000',
  '#DFFF00',
  '#FF00FF',
  '#800000',
];

Map.addLayer(classified.clip(roi), {palette: landcoverPaletter, min: 0, max: 6}, 'Laos Classification');


var areaImage = ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(
      classified)
 
var areas = areaImage.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
      groupField: 1,
      groupName: 'class',
    }),
    geometry: roi.geometry(),
    scale: 500,
    maxPixels: 1e10
    }); 
 
print('Area calculation for the classes(m^2):',areas)
```

Comment: Your assets are not shared.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. Here are the assets. https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ee-lalisaduguma/assets/Laos3prov  and https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ee-lalisaduguma/assets/Lao_pro_training

Comment: Here you find instruction on how to share an asset: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/asset_manager#sharing-assets